# How to change the bin separate for histogram in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot 2 to do plot a histogram. I set the binwidth = 6 because I hope the histogram can get the count for groups(x-axis): (0,6],(6,12],(12,18]..... However, with my code ,I finally got the count for groups: (0,3],(3,9].... as the graph shown below. I hope to know if there is anyway to let the histogram show (0,6],(6,12],(12,18]..... and get the count for each group?

```
    ggplot(aes(x = customer_age), data = data_churn_1) +
geom_histogram( aes(fill = churn), binwidth=6, colour="white") +
stat_bin(binwidth=6, geom="text", colour="black", size=3,
   aes(label=..count..)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,max(data_churn_1$customer_age), 6))+ facet_grid(.~ churn)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Iris, Can you produce a reproducible example along with sample data? It will help us replicate your results and find a possible solution

Comment: You can convert your customer_age to factor using cut(data_churn_1$customer_age, breaks = c(0,3,9,15,21)) then plot the number of observations of each level in the factor